# What happens when a large resource creation request is timed out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's say we have a `PostsController` and a `Post` model that has multiple images.

This images are created in a `after_save` callback.

Now we have a huge request that comes with 20 encoded images which times out when the callback is in the middle of it's excecution.

What is the state now?

- Is the post stored in the DB?
- Where any images created?
- Does it change anything if the images are created in a `before_save` callback?

Comment: What exactly is happening with the images?

Answer (score 0):

The database transaction would be rolled back in any of the callbacks other than `after_commit`. Until the database transaction is committed, it's not persisted onto disk.

If let's say half of the images were processed before the timeout, then that half of the images would be processed. There would be no way to roll that back really.

Here is a link to the [available callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) and the order that they run.

Lastly, it's probably best to run image processing asynchronously via [Active Job](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) so that you're less likely to experience timeout problems.